# Revolution slider and strange symbol instead of arrows

Tags: jquery

I have this simple page (no cms) in which I installed the revolution slider.This is the [demo](http://www.studiosdz.com/revolution/)

The really strange thing is that in some browsers, arrows (forward and backward) are shown correctly and in others there are chinese (or something) characters instead of arrows. For example, on my Chrome browser i see chinese symbols.

I really didn't understand this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press F12 you can see some files aren't found and what can be a problem. But if you add the `!important` in all you arrows CSS, they must display. For example:

```
.tp-leftarrow:before { 
   content: ''; /*for remove the chinese character*/
}

.tp-leftarrow.tparrows.default
{
   position: absolute !important;
   margin-top: -18px;
   left: 20px;
   top: 500px;
}

.tp-leftarrow.default {
   z-index: 100 !important;
   cursor: pointer !important;
   position: relative !important;
   background: url(../assets/large_left.png) no-Repeat 0 0 !important;
   width: 40px !important;
   height: 40px !important;
}

.tp-leftarrow {
   z-index: 100 !important;
   cursor: pointer !important;
   position: relative !important;
   background: url(../assets/large_left.png) no-Repeat top left !important;
   width: 40px !important;
   height: 40px !important;
}
```

The `!important` is used to say that css must be always executed because is more important than the others.