# Chinese character appearing in the slider of the website

Tags: jquery, slider, character

in the slider of the website, sometimes chinese characters appears
That could be due to what? this how it appears

[image]

instead of this (next and precedent)

[image]

Comment: This may happen due to page load problem - slow internet , If you are using font awesome like stuffs. Simply use  `<` sign

Comment: I tried to see the web site with this tool http://www.avivadirectory.com/bethebot/   and it shows this bug, that's why i don't think it is due to slow internet  ,  for the slider it uses the royal slider,  could it be the cause?

Comment: here i found the answer,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521584/revolution-slider-and-strange-symbol-instead-of-arrows